# Calculating the surface area of the ocean at each latitude

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, geometry, geodesy

I am trying to get the surface area of the ocean at each 1° latitude slice. However, for some unknown reason, region -61 which is at latitude -61 has a negative number, and am not sure why that is the case.

How I have approached this is the following:

1. Download a shapefile containing the polygons for oceans from https://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php#goas
2. Load the shapefile into QGIS
3. Create intersection clipping layer with the following Python script:

```
data_file_path = 'latitudes.txt'

data = []
with open(data_file_path, 'r') as file:
    next(file)  # Skip the header line
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():  # Skip empty lines
            parts = line.strip().split('\t')  # Split using tabs
            lower, upper = float(parts[0]), float(parts[1])
            region = f"Region {int(lower)}"  # Generating a default region name based on lower value
            data.append((lower, upper, region))

# Create a new vector layer for clipping polygons
clipping_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "clipping_polygons", "memory")
dataProvider = clipping_layer.dataProvider()
dataProvider.addAttributes([QgsField("region", QVariant.String)])

# Start edit session on the clipping layer
clipping_layer.startEditing()

# Loop through data and create clipping polygons
for range_info in data:
    polygon = QgsFeature()
    pts = [
        QgsPointXY(-180, range_info[0]),
        QgsPointXY(180, range_info[0]),
        QgsPointXY(180, range_info[1]),
        QgsPointXY(-180, range_info[1])
    ]
    polygon.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([pts]))
    polygon.setAttributes([range_info[2]])
    dataProvider.addFeatures([polygon])

# Commit changes and add the clipping layer to the map
clipping_layer.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clipping_layer)
```

An excerpt of latitudes.txt, I have artificially created latitude bands by creating an upper and lower bound

```
Lower   Upper
-90 -89
-89 -88
-88 -87
-87 -86
...
82  83
83  84
84  85
85  86
86  87
87  88
88  89
89  90
```

4. Vector > Intersection with input layer Ocean and clipping layer as the overlay layer
5. Dissolve polygons in intersection layer by region attribute
6. Get the min and max latitude for each polygon by using field calculator for ymax/ymin:

```
y_min(transform($geometry,layer_property(Ocean_latitude_intersection_bands_bylat_c00b00bb_5072_4299_afa6_85457cc3ec97', 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326')
```

```
y_max(transform($geometry,layer_property(Ocean_latitude_intersection_bands_bylat_c00b00bb_5072_4299_afa6_85457cc3ec97', 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326')
```

6. Calculate area of each polygon using “Add geometry attributes” which gives area (in m^2) and perimeter (m) using ‘Ellipsoidal’.

[image: Region -61]

Details of the layer:

[image: Layer details]

Comment: If you want the surface area of a 1x1 degree cell, why are you computing 1x0.99 (or is it 0.99x0.99)? The objects are spheroidal trapezoids before clipping (except for the polar sections, which are spheroidal triangles). The sign error might be due to geometry vertex ordering (right- vs left-hand rule), but looks like a bug.

Comment: That is a fair point, somehow I had the impression that I can't have the start of one polygon being exactly the same as the end of another polygon and made the extra effort to have it close to 1 but not exactly 1, hence 0.99. But now that you mentioned it, it does not make sense at all. I'll promptly change that! About the negative, if its a qgis bug, I'll give it a try in arcgis to see if it remains.. though I am not sure how to deal with that other than deleting that point altogether

Comment: Personally, I'd populate the fishnet as 180x4, compute the areas, then dissolve by degree band, summing areas. This way, you don't have any polygons which are antipodal (180 or more degrees across, as you might find in the south Pacific/Atlantic/Indian/Pacific near 60S). In fact, I expect the bug is *not* failing on antipodal calculation.